# How to set up a proxy server in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, proxy-server

I have installed Windows Server 2012 Data Center Edition at my server. I need to run a proxy server to filter and shape all the outgoing traffic from my server. I know that Microsoft FF TMG do that at Windows Server 2008. However, what is the Microsoft solution for proxy server at Microsoft Server 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no MS solution for a proxy server any more.  TMG was discontinued, and you could not purchase a license for it after December 2012.

There are other proxy servers you can use on Windows, such as our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com), and others such as Squid, CCProxy, Kerio Control etc.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate

Comment: non of the above can be used for enterprise ! it should exist at ist a full features proxy system that be specially designed for microsoft solutions.

Comment: I don't understand.  Plenty of our customers are using WinGate in large enterprise networks.

Comment: Please describe the features that alternative products are missing.